# When we use declare and export keyword in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

In ts file I see declaration of interface:

```
declare interface BlockForm {
}
```

But in others places I see declaration as:

```
export interface BlockFormField {
}
```

What is difference, when we should use declare interface and export interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the export keyword is specifcially to make the interface available to other files.

The declare keyword is not required, however, if used like how you used it then the interface will not be available exernally without the export keyword.

I guess this also works but I don't think declare is adding any value:

export declare interface BlockForm

Comment: So, declare has sense, anyway, what in this case?

Comment: If you are writing your own typescript files, you do not really need to use the declare keyword anywhere.  Declare is to use variables in your typescript code which have been created in from normal javascript files, i.e not typescript.

Comment: I did not get it, could you share example, when it needed

Comment: So typecally you would use declare on functions and variables from external javascript so that you can actually use it in your typescript code. Keywords like export are javascript to make the variable 'public' to other javascript or typescript files.  Declare is about defining 'types' and structure of existing actual functions and variables from non typescript code.

Comment: export is needed say you have: export const x = 5;  then from any other file you can 'import' x and do somthing like console.log(x);

Comment: lets say you had this export in a .js file then to use it in a .ts file you would need to do:
     declare var x: number;

then your .ts file would know its a number.  

however, if you put the original export const x = 5 in a .ts file (as opposed to .js), you would not need the declare as typescript automatically declares it for you

Comment: But export and declare makes variable available in any place where I import file. is not?

Comment: Could you share examle, when it is bad or good to use declare

Comment: Neither good or bad.  It is required in typescript when you are using external javascript code.  The most common example is when you are writing code in .ts (typescript) file and you use external modules from npm.    Many of these are in pure .js.  so you need to tell typescript about it using the 'declare' keyword.

Comment: Share please example, I dont understand what is `It is required in typescript `

Comment: What is it: ` when you are writing code in .ts (typescript)`?

Comment: You can either write code in typescript or javascript.  If you want to use javascript variables from typescript then you need it.